# Manually triggering a PyQt/PySide memory error?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

#### Background

I'm creating a PyQt5 application and have run into the issue

> `Internal c++ Object Already Deleted`

which is caused by a pitfall described on [this page](https://wiki.qt.io/PySide_Pitfalls):

> If a QObject falls out of scope in Python, it will get deleted.

So I was able to avoid this problem by using the optional `parent =` parameter or by storing references to the objects that I had the problem for

#### Question

For testing purposes I'd like to know **if it's possible to manually trigger this issue** (`Internal c++ Object Already Deleted`)

It's an intermittent issue so to be able to test this I need some reliable way of reproducing it

(I don't want to store references to all objects, but rather only keep references when they are needed)

---

I am running PyQt5.15 and Python 3.8

Answer (score 1):

**Previous note:** The error messages are different depending on the binding:

- PyQt5

  ```
  RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type <QtClass> has been deleted
  ```
- PySide2

  ```
  RuntimeError: Internal C++ object (PySide2.<QtModule>.<QtClass>) already deleted.
  ```

---

The problem is caused because the C++ object that manages the python object has been eliminated, and therefore wanting to modify some property of the C++ object through the python object cannot be done obviously.

If you want to reproduce the same problem then just delete the C ++ object using the delete method of sip or shiboken depending on whether you are using PyQt5 or PySide2, respectively.

- PyQt5

  ```
  from PyQt5 import QtCore
  import sip

  o = QtCore.QObject()
  o.setProperty("foo", "bar")
  sip.delete(o)
  o.setProperty("foo", "bar")
  ```
- PySide2

  ```
  from PySide2 import QtCore
  import shiboken2

  o = QtCore.QObject()
  o.setProperty("foo", "bar")
  shiboken2.delete(o)
  o.setProperty("foo", "bar")
  ```

Comment: Thank you for your help! --- I'm still not sure i understand the underlying architecture but Is it possible to trigger something like a (global) garbage collection. IIRC c++ doesn't have that so it would be on the Python level i guess? (I did try using Python's `gc.collect()` but that didn't trigger any of the problems that i've seen).  --- I guess what i'm asking is this: Is it possible to do something similar to what you describe, but globally for all objects? In practical testing terms it's difficult to add your code for all the objects (there's a risk i might miss something).